# Get an error: error: 'std::ios_base& std::ios_base::operator=(const std::ios_base&)' is private

Tags: c++

```
Pseduo code:

 class A : public class B{
    public: 
    A(){}
    ~A(){}
    private:
    string fileName;
    ofstream stream;
  }
```

If I comment out ofstream, the code compiles fine, however with the ofstream, I get the error: 'std::ios_base& std::ios_base::operator=(const std::ios_base&)' is private. Can you please help.

Comment: You are trying to copy assign `A` somewhere. Streams cannot be copied.

Comment: The pseudo code does not help diagnose the problem, at all.

Comment: This has been answered before [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12951162/error-stdios-baseios-baseconst-stdios-base-is-private)

Comment: Thank you very much for your inputs, I was doing a copy of class A which resulted in this issue